# A bundle and its dual having section on a projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a vector bundle of rank $r >2$ on a projective space $\mathbb P^n$ ($n >1$). Let $H^0(\mathbb P^n, E \otimes \mathcal O(-1))=0$ and $H^0(\mathbb P^n, E) \neq 0$.

Can $E^*$ have a section? and if they both have global section, then can we say something specific about the structure or cohomology of the bundle $E$.

One observation is the following: for $r=n=2$, one has $E^* = E(-c)$ where $\text{det}(E) =\mathcal O(c)$. So if $c$ is positive then $E^*$ can't have a section. But what if $n=2, r>2$?

Any remark/suggestion is welcome

Comment: If $E$ is trivial (or has a trivial direct summand) then $E^*$ has a section.

Comment: @sasha, Is this statement if and only if. Can you give me a reference?

Comment: If the composition $\mathcal{O} \to E \to \mathcal{O}$ is non-zero then $\mathcal{O}$ is a direct summand of $E$. But the composition can be zero.

Comment: Take any unstable non-split bundle of rank two on the plane and normalize. Then both the bundle and its dual have sections.